# When I redirect to a page, depending on the country it does not work in https

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code, where according to the country I will redirect to a certain page.
This code works correctly for me in `http` but if I load the html page using`https` it does not do anything.

```
<html>
 <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
              jQuery.ajax( {
              url: '//api.ipstack.com/181.64.157.39?access_key=xxxx',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              success: function(location) {
                // If the visitor is browsing from Canada.
                if (location.country_code === 'CA') {
                  // Redirect him to the Canadian store.
                  //window.top.location.href = 'http://google.com.pe';
                  document.location.href = 'http://google.ca';
                }
              }
            } );
        </script>

 </head>
 <body>
<h2>Hello</h2>


 </body>
</html>
```

Why does this happen, how do I make it work in both?

Comment: Is there any error message in the console?

Comment: Check your browser console and post the error.

Comment: No error in the console

Comment: Try using `https:` in the redirect.

Comment: Not work `https://pymescostarica.mihost.net/geo.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working in HTTPS because your `ipstack` Plan API not support HTTPS. So if you using HTTPS to request, you will return error :

```
{"success":false,"error":{"code":105,"type":"https_access_restricted","info":"Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption."}}
```

So you should edit your AJAX request to force using HTTP instead :

```
<script>
      jQuery.ajax( {
      url: 'http://api.ipstack.com/181.64.157.39?access_key=xxxx',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(location) {
        // If the visitor is browsing from Canada.
        if (location.country_code === 'CA') {
          // Redirect him to the Canadian store.
          //window.top.location.href = 'http://google.com.pe';
          document.location.href = 'http://google.ca';
        }
      }
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, if you know of any alternative to redirect according to the country, tell me. Thanks again.

Comment: I was edited my answer to force HTTP request when call to IPstack, maybe it will work, I will not tested.